# How can I extract or change some of my system settings using Python?

Tags: python, settings

What I am trying to do right now is to see my system settings and data from a python code. For example, I want to be able to print things like the timer of how long until my device goes to sleep/locks, or what kinds of antivirus are installed on it. For now, I have tested with windows-tools.antivirus which has seemed to work, but I wanted to be able to use it on Mac as well.

```
    import windows_tools.bitlocker
    result = windows_tools.bitlocker.get_bitlocker_full_status()
    print(result)
```

^This is what I had tried which worked on a Windows device but I am looking for a Mac equivalent